# No SharePoint 2013 WorkFlow in the list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow

Goal:
Use SharePoint 2013:s workflow in my custom list

Problem:
In the picture below it only has SharePoint 2010 Workflow only.

What method should I do in order to find out why I don't have SharePoint 2013 workflow?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which version of SharePoint Designer are you running?

Comment: it is version 2013

Comment: The SharePoint site you have open is also 2013? Is Workflow fully setup on your 2013 SP instance? Check this out: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c3f7dab2-30eb-451d-9299-a331ce41ddf8/the-option-for-the-sharepoint-2013-workflow-platform-is-not-available-because-the-workflow-service?forum=sharepointcustomization

Comment: SharePoint site is 2013.

Comment: "Is Workflow fully setup on your 2013 SP instance?" How do I review it? I'm a newbie in SP2013

Comment: If you are still looking for help, I have a blog written on how to configure Workflow manager in SharePoint 2013. [Read More](http://tech.just4sharing.com/Pages/tech/Configuring-SharePoint-2013-to-support-workflow-Management-Service.aspx)

Comment: I have a question. From the link that you have provided. One of the instruction's message "Step 23:  Give this command "Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://xxxx" -WorkflowHostUri "http://xxxx:12291" - AllowOAuthHttp
". Where do I locate the WorkflowHostUri in my computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that you have fully installed and configured workflow for SP2013: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193478.aspx

That should make the "SharePoint 2013 Workflow" Platform Type appear in SPD2013.

Comment: Based on the new picture (IIS) above, it tells me that I do not have workflow manager installed. What is your experience?

Comment: Go for the workflow installation. See the TechNet articles I posted in the updated answer. Best of luck getting it setup and working!

Comment: Have you configured Workflow Manager in your farm?

Comment: I'm started doing it.   
I have a question. From the link that you have provided. One of the instruction's message "Step 23: Give this command "Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "xxxx"; -WorkflowHostUri "xxxx:12291"; - AllowOAuthHttp ". Where do I locate the WorkflowHostUri in my computer